# Transform json object with jq, transforming values with base64 decode

Tags: json, linux, bash, base64, jq

I'm working with a json object that looks like this:

```
{
    "someattrinbute": "somevalue",
    "data": {
        "SOMENAME": "...",
        "SOMEOTHERNAME": "...",
        ...
    }
}
```

Where all the values in the "data" object are base64-encoded.  I want to produce the same json, but with all the property values in the "data" object are base64-decoded.

I believe this would involve using "to_entries", "from_entries", and the "@base64d" function, but I can't see how to package this all together.

I'll be doing this in a bash shell script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[map_values](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) can be used for to apply the `@base64d` function to each element of the object.

For example

`jq '.data|map_values(@base64d)' example.json`

Comment: Despite the good information provided in the first answer, I actually find that this answer is more concise.  The first answer doesn't point out that I still have to add another filter at the end to remap it to ".data".

Comment: The first answer solves the stated problem, i.e. "I want to produce the same json ..."

Answer (score 9):

Given example.json:

```
{
    "someattrinbute": "somevalue",
    "data": {
        "SOMENAME": "MTIz",
        "SOMEOTHERNAME": "NDU2"
        
    }
}
```

the invocation:

```
$ jq '.data[] |= @base64d' example.json
```

produces:

```
{
  "someattrinbute": "somevalue",
  "data": {
    "SOMENAME": "123",
    "SOMEOTHERNAME": "456"
  }
}
```

---

Footnote: at least as of September 2022, `gojq` (the Go implementation of jq) has a less restrictive implementation of `@base64d` than the C-based implementation.

Comment: Actually, could you amend this answer with an explanation of what exactly that is doing? I make basic use of jq every day, but details like this are a little baffling.

Comment: The answer is so short that it can serve as a guide to what to look for in the jq manual.  A good way to learn is to have a challenge and a guide.

Comment: I guess this is really just a higher-level question about jq, but I find it curious that "jq .data" will JUST emit the "data" block, and omit any other peer properties, but "jq '.data|=.", takes all the original data (not omitting the peer properties), but processes the "data" block with the filter (being an identity filter, in this case).

Comment: Yes, that's the magic of jq, though it's not that different from C in this particular case.

Comment: I think the confusion @DavidM.Karr had (as I just had) is that, in langs like JS, an assignment returns the result of the assignment, so I guessed that this line would assign stuff in `.data[]` and then return that result, and not everything around it. So I guess the quirk here is that jq first processes the `|=` assignment, which does not return a result, and then it will return everything because we haven't told it what to return. Adding `| .data` then returns _just_ the data. Hope that makes sense!